# Datatables make all bordered cells when export to excel

Tags: excel, datatables

Thanks in advance. How to make all bordered excel cells when export? I could not find documantation or manual about that.

Comment: export as in print or export to pdf? Can you not make borders in excel sheet before export?

Comment: Can you not make borders in excel sheet before export? - exactly

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/excelBorder.html

Answer (score 1):

To add a border around each Excel cell, you can use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {

      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'excelHtml5',
          title: '', // no title row in excel sheet
          text: 'Excel', // label for the export button
          customize: function ( xlsx ) {
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
            $( 'row c', sheet ).attr( 's', '25' );
          }
        }
      ]

    } );

} );

</script>
```

This takes advantage of one of the [built-in styles](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Built-in-styles) available to DataTables when exporting data to Excel. Specifically, the `attr( 's', '25' )` function uses style number 25 (normal text with thin black border).

Here is an example of the output:

[image]